# Where is the EAR file located?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ear

I created an application with [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) and now want to publish it on the internet. For that reason I need the [EAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29) file. But I was not able to find it.

I searched every directory, but I could not see it. Where does the `EAR` file stay in the file directory?

I made my project with [Eclipse 4.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Juno) and an Apache server.

Comment: Did you explicitly created EAR through your IDE?

Comment: Do you have Enterprise application project in your workspace? If yes, then why dont you export EAR from your IDE again?

Comment: Yes I have enterprise application project in my workspace. But how can I **export `EAR` again from the IDE**? I did not geet that part. Actually I am new to this, so don't have a good experience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your project. Click Export then 'Export...'. Type 'EAR'. New dialog box will open. Give the correct destination. You're good to go. :)

Comment: It gets stuck and never completes. You have to export to a local drive.